# ADB in android studio keeps showing same error message and does not start

Tags: android, adb

My ADB install does not work, it does not start or show any info. I keep getting the same error message over and over again:

```
18:14   Unable to run 'adb': null

18:14   '/Users/jorandob/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

If I try to start ADB manually it just doesn't show anything.

I tried so far:

- Restart server
- Reinstall ADB
- Reinstall Android Studio

I'm on mac os X 10.11.6 and not using any special emulator.
If its helpful information, I'm using ionic.

Terminal ADB:

`Jorans-iMac:~ jorandob$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 0e9850346394-android`

Comment: Have you added the path to the "adb" executable to your ~/.bash_profile  $PATH variable?

Comment: @Cbr if i run adb version this is the response Jorans-iMac:~ jorandob$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
Revision 0e9850346394-android So i think its linked properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue, it occurs if you run java and ADB at the same time.

to fix it stop all java processes in the activity monitor.

Comment: Helped with "ADB not responding" as well.