# Android Studio emulators appear in the AVD Manager but not in the Run menu

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-studio-3.0

The picture says it all.

I have tried opening the emulator in the avd manager and access it through the run menu without success.

Background info:
 - I recently upgraded to MacOS High Sierra.
 - I have updated Android Studio to 3.0 Beta 7 trying to solve the issue.
 - The commands "emulator" and "avd" are unrecognized commands now.
 - I am also using react-native, accessing the emulator from react-native run-android and android studio too, doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Comment: where is the picture ?

Comment: what error does it gives when you start your emulator?

Comment: The emulator will only start from the AVD Manager menu. There is no error. Simply AS wouldn't recognize it and I cannot load my apps to it.

Comment: The expected behaviour is to have the AVD devices mirrored in this run screen.

Comment: from your screenshot, it gives an impression that you haven't started your virtual device and have only created them.

Comment: Until you run your virtual device it will not show in deployment target

Answer (score 0):

If the project API matches you emulator API version and emulator is running try restarting ADB.
In Android studio - Tools -> Android -> Enable Adb integration and then once again to turn it on. Or

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: So is your emulator running?

Comment: The emulator is running. 
Still, the devices listed in the adb should mirror in the run screen as usual and I cannot load my app into it through Android Studio.

Comment: Check in your build.gradle file if the targetSDK and minimumSdk version is lower or equal to the sdk version of your Emulator.

Comment: To test I have made a new project with min version API 15 and still cannot see the 6 emulators that should be appearing.

Comment: I've deleted all Android Studio an app from my Macbook, re-installed, created a new project, a new emulator and still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get my adb devices back in sync with Android Studio. It was an adb port problem at root.

"
I finally resolved my issue, it occurs if you run java and ADB at the same time.

to fix it stop all java processes in the activity monitor.

shareeditflag
answered Mar 10 at 20:25

Joran Dob
163114
"
[ADB in android studio keeps showing same error message and does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701920/adb-in-android-studio-keeps-showing-same-error-message-and-does-not-start)